# How to properly type hint usage of child classes in list?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

How do I properly type hint this:

```py
from typing import Optional

class A: ...
class B(A): ...
class C(A): ...

my_dict: dict[str, list[Optional[A]]] = {"b": [], "c": []}

b: list[Optional[B]] = [B()]
c: list[Optional[C]] = [C()]
my_dict["b"] = b
my_dict["c"] = c
```

I obatain the following error in `mypy`:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "list[B | None]", target has type "list[A | None]")  [assignment]
```

This works but is not what I want:

```py
b: list[Optional[A]] = [B()]
c: list[Optional[A]] = [C()]`
```

Naively I assumed that the information would be inherited that `B` and `C` are children of `A` and thus the assignment is valid since this works:

```py
bb: A = B()
cc: A = C()
```

Am I approaching it the wrong way? Can anyone help out?

I don't want it too verbose. Assume I have longer class names for `B` and `C` in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using Optional here.

All three classes are instances of A so it's just:

```
class A: ...

class B(A): ...

class C(A): ...

my_dict: dict[str, list[A]] = {"b": [], "c": []}

my_dict["b"] = [B()]
my_dict["c"] = [C()]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes indeed this is valid. Thanks! The usage of `[None]` is not necessary and thus also `Optional`.  I maybe got confused with the empty list and `Optional`.